# reactflow js delete example on website not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement the delete that is described on the bottom of the page here: https://reactflow.dev/docs/getting-started/

However, the backspace key does not seem to do anything. Being new to react I'm not quite sure what's wrong. (Also, the example here to delete the edge also seems not to work working https://reactflow.dev/examples/edge-with-button ?)

Below are the relevant files. Any help is much appreciated.

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactFlow, { removeElements, addEdge } from "react-flow-renderer";

import './App.css';
//import _default from 'react-flow-renderer/dist/components/Handle';


const initialElements = [
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'input', // input node
    data: { label: 'Input Node' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 25 },
  },
  // default node
  {
    id: '2',
    // you can also pass a React component as a label
    data: { label: <div>Default Node</div> },
    position: { x: 100, y: 125 },
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'output', // output node
    data: { label: 'Output Node' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 250 },
  },
  // animated edge
  { id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2', animated: true },
  { id: 'e2-3', source: '2', target: '3' },
];

export default function App() { 
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(initialElements);
  const onElementsRemove = (elementsToRemove) => setElements((els) => removeElements(elementsToRemove, els));
  const onConnect =  (params) => setElements((els) => addEdge(params, els));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: 1024 }}>
        <ReactFlow 
          elements={elements}
          onElementsRemove={onElementsRemove}
          onConnect={onConnect}
          deleteKeyCode={46} /* 'delete'-key */
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ); 
};
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import ReactFlow from 'react-flow-renderer';


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  //document.getElementById('root')
  rootElement
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

**index.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

**Note 1**
After more experimentation, on a mac, it's hitting ctrl + delete the key. Not sure why, however, the delete button in the second example still does not work.

**Note 2**
after even more experimentation and after adding code to drag and drop nodes, it has become fn+delete. It seems like character 46 changes?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you've already found the solution, but for just in case there're people like me looking for ways to use keys other than "Backspace" to delete a node or edge, I write what I found:

**Putting "deleteKeyCode=..." as a property of <ReactFlow> tag solves the problem**.

I clicked a node or edge, pressed delete key, saw the node or edge gone with the following code:

```
const [flowDiagram, setFlowDiagram] = useState([]);

<ReactFlow ...
    onInit={r=>{setFlowDiagram(r)}} 
    deleteKeyCode={["Backspace","Delete"]}
    onPaneContextMenu={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();addNode(e)}}
    onNodesDelete={(n)=>yourFunction1(n}    // as needed
    onEdgesDelete={(t)=>yourFunction2(t)    // as needed
/>

// In my case, right-click draws a new node on the pane
function addNode(e){
    let newId = MAKE_YOUR_OWN;
    let newNode = {
        id: newId, 
        type: "default",
        data: {label: `[${newId}]`, ADD_IF_NECESSARY}, 
        position:{UP_TO_YOU}
    };
    flowDiagram.addNodes(newNode);
}
```

BTW, "preventDefault" suppresses context menu that you usually see in web pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are two React libraries: `reactflow` & `react-flow-renderer`.

If you are using `reactflow` library, use prop `deleteKeyCode` like:

```
deleteKeyCode={['Backspace', 'Delete']}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).